# Transition in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

I have a jquery code that adds css animation classes.the code works properly in chrome,firefox and other modern browsers.
this is what i use to run an animation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    doanim('body','flipInY');
});
```

and what i have in doanim function is:

```
function doanim(ido,x,ext) {
if (ext===undefined){
    ext="";
}
eval("$('"+ido+"').addClass(x + ' animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){$(this).removeClass(x + '   animated');"+ext+"});");
};
```

as i said it works properly running animations perfectly
but the problem started when i wrote the code as seen down here

```
$('#btnstart').click(function(){
$('body:not(#sp3,#sp4,#sp5)').addClass('rotateOut' + ' animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('rotateOut animated');$("#sp1,#sp2,#inpcontainer,#btnstart,#titledash,#back,#logo-right").hide();$("#sp3,#sp4,#sp5").addClass('bounceInLeft' + ' animated');$("#sp3").show();
    $("#sp3").css({"opacity": 0,"-moz-opacity":0}).one('mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        ///it's gonna not showing #sp4 as it's supposed to here in firefox tested with alert its entering this part
        $("#sp4").show();
        $("#sp4").css("opacity", 0).one('mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
            $("#sp5").show();
            $("#sp5").css("opacity", 0).one('mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
                alert("d");
            });
        });
    });
})
});
```

this code is supposed to rotate out specified objects,show up #sp3 with animation and on animaton end set opacity to 0 and do the same thing with #sp4,#sp5
it works pretty fine in Google chrome.but in Firefox(v30) it's doing everything pretty fine until #sp3 's opacity decreation.so when #sp3 is disappeared it's gonna stop and not showing #sp4 as it's supposed to do.
i would be glad to help me out with this problem
thanks everyone

Comment: Maybe use all of these: -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity:0.5; 
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;

Comment: tnx Piwwoli for your comment i replaced css part with {"-ms-filter":"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)", "filter": "alpha(opacity=0)", "-moz-opacity":"0",  "-khtml-opacity": "0", "opacity": "0"}. unfortunately didn't solve the problem